# Use std::function with lambda and variadic template

Tags: c++, lambda, callback, variadic-templates

I found some nice loop function on internet, but wasn't able to make it my own. And the code was uncommented so that didn't help.

**Original code :**

```
  template <typename T> struct identity { typedef T type; };

  template <typename ... Components>
  void each(typename identity<std::function<void(Base base, Components&...)>>::type f) {
    //do stuff
  }
```

The goal is to unpack some data from a class and apply the function on it, Foo there is the manager which contain the object, and this object has some int member inside.I hope it's clear enough.

I'd like to achieve something like that:

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

class Foo {

  template < typename ... T >
  void  for_each(std::function<void(T&...)> func) {
    std::cout << "for_each" << std::endl;
  }
};

int main() {

  Foo  test;
  test.for_each<int>([](int& data) {
    std::cout << "main" << std::endl;
  });
  return 0;
}
```

But I have this error instead:

```
Test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
Test.cpp:17:4: error: no matching function for call to ‘Foo::for_each(main()::<lambda(int&)>)’
   });
    ^
Test.cpp:7:9: note: candidate: template<class ... T> void Foo::for_each(std::function<void(T& ...)>)
   void  for_each(std::function<void(T&...)> func) {
         ^~~~~~~~
Test.cpp:7:9: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
Test.cpp:17:4: note:   ‘main()::<lambda(int&)>’ is not derived from ‘std::function<void(T& ...)>’
   });
    ^
```

Seems like there was some bugs with this code, I hope it's not the case anymore. If you have some advice to make this code works, well you'll make a man happy.

Comment: A lambda function such as you are using can be used to construct a `std::function<void(int&)>` but it can't be used to construct a `std:;function<void(int& ...)`. It's not clear from your post what's the behavior you are expecting.

Comment: @RSahu it's a loop which unpack data from a class. I'll add it to the question if it can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you plan to use non-capturing lambdas only, you can use a function pointer as an argument and let the lambda decay to such a type.
It follows a minimal, working example:

```
#include <iostream>

class Foo {
public:
  template < typename ... T>
  void  for_each(void(*func)(T&...)) {
    std::cout << "for_each" << std::endl;
  }
};

int main() {
  Foo  test;
  test.for_each(+[](int& data) {
    std::cout << "main" << std::endl;
  });
  return 0;
}
```

---

If you can deal with a class template, another possible approach is the following one:

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

template < typename ... T >
class Foo {
public:
  void  for_each(std::function<void(T&...)> func) {
    std::cout << "for_each" << std::endl;
  }
};

int main() {
  Foo<int> test;
  test.for_each([](int& data) {
    std::cout << "main" << std::endl;
  });
  return 0;
}
```

---

Note that, if you are not actually interested in the type `T`, you can use a generic type and get away with it:

```
#include <iostream>

class Foo {
public:
  template<typename F>
  void  for_each(F &&func) {
    std::cout << "for_each" << std::endl;
  }
};

int main() {
  Foo  test;
  test.for_each([](int& data) {
    std::cout << "main" << std::endl;
  });
  return 0;
}
```

It works with both capturing and non.capturing lambdas.

Comment: Thought you were going to present an `invoke`-based solution skypjack ;-)

Comment: @RichardHodges Tempted, then I thought that OP wants to know what's `T` to use it somehow in the function.

Comment: @skypjack The solution I was searching was the second one I think (not sure the operator+ trick will be natural to use for a library). But if you don't mind I'd like to know what is the `invoke`-based solution (never heard of it). I'll go check any solution in detail. Anyway thanks like always :)

Comment: @MathieuVanNevel http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/invoke

Comment: @RichardHodges Yet to come. :-( ... Anyway, SO (C++ tag) will be funny soon. :-)

Comment: @RichardHodges seems pretty verbose, but a good pair for concepts, I'll try it to see. Thanks!

Comment: @skypjack sorry to bother, but do you know where I can find more information about the second solution? Can't figure out why it's working and not the code of the question...

Answer (score 1):

If you specify a `std::function` as the argument type, then a `std::function` must be passed. A lambda is not a `std::function`, but it can be used to create one.

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

class Foo {

  public:
  template < typename ... T >
  void  for_each(std::function<void(T&...)> func) {
    std::cout << "for_each" << std::endl;
  }
};

int main() {

  Foo  test;
  test.for_each<int>(std::function<void(int&)>([](int& data) {
    std::cout << "main" << std::endl;
  }));
  return 0;
}
```

This may not be what you want (at the moment, I can only guess at that), bu this edit at least allows the example to compile.

Comment: It's not really what I was hoping, but maybe it'll be better. I was thinking the cast was implicit, thanks for the warning.

Answer (score 1):

Based on

> The goal is to unpack some data from a class and apply the function on it, Foo there is the manager which contain the object, and this object has some int member inside

I think you are looking for something like:

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class Foo {

   public:

      template < typename T >
         void  for_each(std::function<void(T&)> func) {
            std::cout << "for_each" << std::endl;
            for ( int i : data)
            {
               func(i);
            }
         }

      std::vector<int> data;
};

int main() {

  Foo test;
  test.data = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

  test.for_each<int>([](int& data) {
    std::cout << "In main, data:" << data << std::endl;
  });
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes seems to me that it is, what I was looking for. I'll take a break and check it to be sure. Thanks :)

Comment: The idea is there, but the real problem is still there. I need a variatic template. I need to be able to do `for_each<Class1>`, `for_each<Class2,Class3> `... I'll update the question with the original code.